# Flutter user not being able to log in from firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build a log in and logout feature in flutter using firebase auth. I have created the UI and have even assigned controllers to the email and password. My project is also connected to firebase and all relevant packages installed. After I log in, a new page is supposed to open displaying "Signed In" and if not logged in then display the login page. I have entered the correct email and password according to what I created on firebase but am not being shown the home page as it should be, instead I am still on the login page.

The following is the code:

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import 'package:my_sample/widgets/main_page.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**main_page.dart:**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_sample/widgets/home_page.dart';
import 'package:my_sample/widgets/login_page.dart';

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return const HomePage();
              } else {
                return const LoginPage();
              }
            }
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

**login_page.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // text controllers
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future signIn() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailController.text.trim(),
      password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Icon(
                  Icons.android,
                  size: 100,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 75),
                // Hello Again!
                Text(
                  'Hello Again!',
                  style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                    fontSize: 52,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Welcome back, you\'ve been missed!',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 50),
                // email textfield
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),

                // password textfield
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _passwordController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                      filled: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                // sign in button
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: signIn,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Sign In',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 25),

                // not a member? register now
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: const [
                    Text(
                      'Not a member?',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      ' Register Now',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home_page.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Text('Signed in'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work.

1 - Make sure the user is created in Firebase Console (authentication).

2 - If you are not using Google SignIn, I suggest using the recent launched "automatic" Firebase configuration (instead of the manual). That will rule out any configuration issues you might have.
FirebBase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

3 - Check for errors when calling signIn method:
await FirebaseAuth.instance
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
email: _emailController.text.trim(),
password: _passwordController.text.trim(),
).catchError((error) => print(error));

Comment: Thanks. This worked. However, I was not able to successfully implement point number 2 but point number 3 helped